# Power BI Service - Unable to refresh a postgresql source which doesn't support encrypted connections

Tags: postgresql, powerbi

I'm trying to refresh the data on a PostgreSQL server running on AWS with no SSL certificate on it.
I'm able to refresh the datasets in the Power BI Desktop. However, I'm neither able to refresh nor able to perform a scheduled refresh in the Power BI service. 
How do we connect to a Postgres server which has no SSL certificate on it and perform a refresh on power BI service?
I'm getting the following error: [image: Power BI Service error while refreshing]

Comment: I don't know, but couldn't you configure SSL support in the database?

Comment: I can. But my question is, won’t I be able to connect to servers with no ssl support on it? Other vendors do provide it out of the box.

Comment: So does PostgreSQL. You just have to configure it. But I share your concern that it is not nice to force SSL mode.

Comment: Apparently, even after enabling SSL, Postgres accepts both encrypted and unencrypted connections. One has to force SSL in order to go all-in with SSL-only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. The option was actually under the advanced settings of the dataset that was added to the gateway.

[image: Postgres with no encryption]