# Unable to create a report in Power BI through PostgreSQL dataset

Tags: postgresql, powerbi

I am unable to create reports from PostgreSQL dataset in Power BI service(from a remote server, not encryted). It works in Power BI desktop where I have created datasource and published as Power BI service.

[Error while creating report in Power BI App, screen dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWk7Q.png)

I am able to refresh the data set too in Power BI service but could not create report.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052763/power-bi-service-unable-to-refresh-a-postgresql-source-which-doesnt-support-e?rq=1

Comment: **@Jonee** I have seen this link but there is no gateway connection required as the data source is in cloud server. Link did not help.